# Exoplayer not playing videos with long durations

Tags: android, android-studio, exoplayer, exoplayer2.x

I've been using Exoplayer for quite a while to play short local videos gotten from Mediastore but now when I try to play videos with a duration of one hour or above, it hooks and doesn't play anything.

And instead of showing the total duration to be 1:15:02 it'll show this instead 99:34:56
What is possibly the issue?
How do I fix this?

Is it because I'm using a mediaItem not a mediaSource?

Here's my code sample

```
MediaItem mediaItem = MediaItem.fromUri(video.getPath);
// Set the media item to be played.
player.setMediaItem(mediaItem);
// Prepare the player.
player.prepare();
// Start the playback.
player.play();
```

Comment: did you tried with media source?

Comment: Yes, sir. I tried using a progressiveMediaSource but the issue still persists, though it might be because I'm doing it wrong. A code sample will be highly appreciated.